# Why did the lords and ladies easily believe that Bran has powers?

Tags: game-of-thrones

When Bran got his Three Eyed Raven Powers, it is reasonable to see Bran's company (Meera, Hodor, etc.) believe that he has these visions because they can actually see even the Children of the Forest.

But how did Tyrion and many others easily believe to what Bran says? Personally, I think it should take time to believe how someone with visions can see the past and present. Especially that Tyrion didn't even believe there were White Walkers until he saw one.

Comment: Bran: I know how many fingers you're holding behind your back.

Comment: Well he knew he'd have to bring his own chair. Drogon: "I am taking mommy and destroying the throne. If my mommy doesn't get to sit on it, none of you do, Bring your own damn chair".......Bran: "Aha! I _have_ a chair, I foresaw I'd need it".....Lords and Ladies: "What a wise guy, he should be our King".

Comment: Bran can tell everyone their deepest darkest secrets. Remember when he casually mentioned to Petyr Baelish, "**Chaos is a ladder.**" With that kind of power, he can easily convince anyone within 10 seconds.

Comment: They showed us how he convinced Dolorous Ed.  They showed us how he convinced Sansa.  They showed us how he convinced Arya.  Having established a clear pattern of behavior, they apparently assumed that viewers could figure out how everybody else would be convinced of his abilities.